# Show number of articles in menu

Tags: categories, menus

I want to display a number of articles in a certain category which is hooked to a menu item. It should look like Bootstrap's "badge" component. Now I've got:

[image: Current - without]

and what I want to achieve:

[image: What I want]

Do I have to modify WP's code, or is there a plugin for it? I've tried to find one, but none of the ones I saw addresses this specific situation.

It would be best if the counter showed only published articles, but it's a minor thing - it's probably a matter of adding a condition when retrieving the number of articles from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be useful to create a custom walker for your menu. In the following code example I made use of the Menu Item Object. You can take a look at the object output  [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items).

An object type is specified for every menu item. So I just compare if the object is a category. If yes I made use of the specified object ID to get the category + category count. Last but not least I just wrap the category count with a span at the end of the link. I hope it works for you.

Here the code example:

```
class Menu_Category_Count extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    var $number = 1;

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        // Get Category + Category Count
        $category_count = "";
        if ($item->object == "category") {
            $category = get_category($item->object_id);
            $category_count = $category->category_count;
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ($item->object == "category") ? '<span class="count">'.$category_count.'</span>': '';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

}
```

Than just call the custom nav walker where you get your nav menu like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        ....,
        "walker"            => new Menu_Category_Count(),
    )
);
```

If you never dealed with a custom nav walker take a look at [this tutorial at tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I only had to change `$category['category_count']` to `$category->category_count`. I also had to change `($item_object = "category")` to `($item->object == "category")`. Now I get "Projekty4" which is fine, it's just a matter of styling the number properly with CSS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok sorry for the mistakes, my bad. But glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey by using the code snippet you can get the number of article within the category

```
$postsInCat = get_term_by('name','NAMEOFCATEGORY','category');
$postsInCat = $postsInCat->count;
echo $postsInCat;
```

I think it help you